# Bootstrap Grid Class Usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Regarding this [example](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/NNvBQW) of making a responsive list of `<ul>` and `<li>`,
I don't understand the principle of the following line:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
```

which makes the responsive design of lists happen.
I understand each class among the four, but not their function when combined.

Comment: Each of the classes describes the width of the div, but only for certain screen sizes. `col-xs-12` applies for everything, but can be overridden by any of the others; `col-sm-10` applies for every screen larger than `xs`, and takes precedence over it; `col-md-8` applies for every screen larger than `sm`, and takes precedence over it, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you know some of them, I assume the following ones (i.e the bootstrap grid layout which is 12 columns):

```
col-xs-12 => Take full width for size extra small
col-sm-10 => width 10/12 width for small
col-md-8 => width 8/12 width for medium
```

The remaining ones:

```
col-sm-offset-1 => put a margin of 1 col width on the left for small
col-md-offset-2 => put a margin of 2 cols with on the left for medium
```

Comment: Maybe include a link to the bootstrap grid documentation too :)

Answer (score 1):

Full width when the screen size is xs, 10 column widths at size small - pushed over by 1 column, 8 column width at size medium - pushed over by 2 columns.

The sm and md in the offset classes tells you which size it is affecting. So `.col-md-offset-2` means that of the 12 grid columns across the screen, the `col-md-8` is going to start 2 columns over, so it starts in the 3rd column position. taking up 3-12, 8 columns in total.